# .htaccess redirect with query string on subdomain isn't working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use htaccess to redirect a URL like:

http://subdomain.domain.com/[anytexthere]/ to redirect to

http://www.domain2.com/something/something/[theanytexthere]/

But all I keep getting is a 404 error when trying to access http://subdomain.domain.com/test/, here is the .htaccess sample:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule http://www.domain2.com/some/path/%1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Does it not get redirected at all? Is this .htaccess enabled?

Comment: Hey, no redirect at all, if i remove the query string part it will redirect but i need the query string. Yes mod_rewrite is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no query string in your source or target URL. You just need `REQUEST_URI` to be redirected.

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =subdomain.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain2.com/some/path%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Comment: that just produces garbage at the end of the redirect url %25%7bREQUEST_URI%7b

Comment: ah it worked you just had a typo on the end, thanks , htaccess never been a strong point for me!

Comment: Ah sorry, typo is fixed now.